# Where is ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json saved for Google Drive API Python Implementation?

Tags: python, json, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive Quickstart Python API from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python). I want to find the 'drive-python-quickstart.json' file on my windows system. Where is it actually stored? Where is '~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json' in Windows?

> ## If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
>
> ## at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
>
> SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
>
> CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
>
> APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'

Comment: At default Quickstart, 'drive-python-quickstart.json' is saved at home directory. If you use command prompt on windows, you can get home directory by ``echo %HOMEPATH%``. If you use terminal with shell, you can get it by ``echo $HOME``. If you want to put it on your current working directory, please change ``credential_path`` to ``os.path.join("./", 'drive-python-quickstart.json')``. At that time, please delete ``home_dir, credential_dir, if``.

Comment: Tanaike -- you should make your comment an answer so we can upvote it. (Also, thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

`~` refers to the **Root** location, in Windows.
 This can be for instance

`C:\Users\<*user-name*>\.credentials` folder.

Where `<user-name>` is your username (i.e. `C:\Users\John\.credentials`)

You will find the `drive-python-quickstart.json` file over there.

Comment: Mine was in the C:\Users\<*user-name*>\Documents\.credentials

Answer (score 1):

I found it! In the Mac terminal, I used this command to go to the home directory: `cd ~`

I ran the `ls` command to see what was in there, but no .credentials directory. I tried `sudo ls` and bam, there it was. I used the `rm` command to delete the file and it worked for me.