# DotNet GMail Quickstart application name

Tags: gmail-api

I wrote my first Gmail API program in C# starting with the help I found
at:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

The problem is the name of the app, according to Google, listed under "Third-party apps with account access", is "Quickstart", which is not a very descriptive name for my app.  Am I stuck with that name?

I've tried to search the source files for "Quickstart" and can't find out where the name is coming from. I've made sure to specify my preferred name in the ApplicationName parameter of the service connect.

```
 // Create Gmail API service.
 var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = "EMailChecker",
 });
```

But that makes no difference. I've tried removing access via my Google account and re-running the program to let it authenticate, but that does not affect. It still shows up as "Quickstart".

So am I stuck with that name? Other than that, the program is working well.

Answer (score 0):

It is also stated in the documentation that if you are modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at `~/.credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json`.

You may check this link for reference: [Where is ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json saved for Google Drive API Python Implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052538/where-is-credentials-drive-python-quickstart-json-saved-for-google-drive-api)