# Where is the ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json file from using the Google Drive API on my computer?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I've been trying to find `~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json` on my computer to delete but I just cannot find it anywhere. Yes, I have tried the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052538/where-is-credentials-drive-python-quickstart-json-saved-for-google-drive-api) but they don't help.
I've looked in my computers root, homepath, user folders, appdata, documents, anywhere I can think of that it could be and it's nowhere.
Does anyone know where this file is hiding?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the token.json folder in the project's bin directory, it will accomplish what you are looking for. I couldn't find `~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json` either. The comment in the [quick-start sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) is just wrong as no such file exists.

[image]